# Continuity from complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function, such as: $f(X)=Y$.
If $X$ is complete, does it imply $Y$ is complete?

Comment: If $X$ has the discrete metric, any function on $X$ is continuous.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic, but one is complete and the other isnt.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $X = Y = \mathbb{N}$ with metrics
$$d_X(m, n) = |m - n|$$
and
$$d_Y(m, n) = |2^{-m} - 2^{-n}|.$$
The identity map is a continuous bijection from $X$ to $Y$, $X$ is complete, but $Y$ is not (because $0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ is a Cacuhy sequence without a limit point).

Comment: ? $d_Y(m,n)$ is not a metric.  $d_Y(n,m) = |2^n - 2^{-m}| \ne |2^m - 2^{-n}|$.

Comment: Oops, there was a typo. It should be $|2^{-m} - 2^{-n}|$. Fixed, thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $Y = \mathbb{R}^+$, $f(x) = e^x$.
Then $f(X) = Y$, but the Cauchy sequence
$$
1, \frac12, \frac13, \frac14, \frac15, \ldots \in Y
$$
does not converge to a point in $Y$.